# Resampling dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory, resampling

I'm trying to resample and plot the average temperature of a city from a dataframe by year using Pandas. I'm successfully creating a copy of the data however, I keep running into this issue.
[image]

Note: The column name of the date is dt.

Comment: it looks like `df` just doesn't have the key "Y". Check the contents of df to make sure it has what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, upon doing some debugging it appears when I create a copy of the dataframe and store it in 'df2' it is not a dataframe but a series.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling pandas to look for a column called 'Y' but the KeyError is telling you that this pandas data frame doesn't have a column called 'Y'

Here's a more detailed explanation of the error.

[https://www.statology.org/pandas-keyerror/#:~:text=One%20error%20you%20may%20encounter%20when%20using%20pandas,accidental%20space%20before%20or%20after%20the%20column%20name.[KeyError][1]](https://www.statology.org/pandas-keyerror/#:%7E:text=One%20error%20you%20may%20encounter%20when%20using%20pandas,accidental%20space%20before%20or%20after%20the%20column%20name.%5BKeyError%5D%5B1%5D)

Like the above answer is saying you have only saved the average temperature column. 'dt' and 'Y' do not exist in your new df2. Call your df2 and look at the columns you have available.

Try this

```
df2 = df(df["City"] == "Aden") & (df["Country"=="Yemen")].copy()
df2[df2.column == 'Y']).mean().plot()
```

My original answer still answers what is causing your error.

Comment: I tried changing it to the key of the date column ('dt') and still received the same error.

Comment: I updated my answer. You don't have column dt or Y in your df2. You only have average temperature.

Answer (score 0):

You only save the AverageTemperature column. Try keeping all columns, or at least include the Y column too:

```
df2 = df[(df['City'] == 'Aden') & (df['Country'] == 'Yemen')].copy()
```